# Internet user stats websites - including feature like cookies, resolution, OS etc

Tags: statistics, web-standards, usage-statistics

Are there any good websites which feature how internet users use the internet. Which features stats like if they use cookies, browser type and version, the OS they use and a resolution? Or is the information used to design/build websites a standard, or do web designers/developers work to what they assume would be the most common and develop for that?

I suppose what I am asking is what standards do they work to? Industry standard, current and forthcoming use or is it just assumed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gs.statcounter.com/ (not the statistic: drop down)

or

http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

or google search for more

Comment: Thanks! Both exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, especially the info in the first website :)
Regarding cookies, is it just accepted that 99% of internet users have them enabled?